# Customize style for jQuery UI checkbox

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui

I'm using [jQueryUI checkboxes without icon](http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/#no-icons) but cannot find how to modify/override the checkbox style using CSS.

For example I'd like to add a red border on "checked" buttons, but the following CSS doesn't work (I deduced the classes from the DevTools Elements pane):

```
.ui-checkboxradio-label .ui-corner-all .ui-button .ui-widget .ui-checkboxradio-checked .ui-state-active {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}

.checkbox-noicon .ui-checkboxradio .ui-helper-hidden-accessible {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}
```

I also tried modifying the style of the input's "checked" state directly, also with no effect:

```
input[type=checkbox]:checked {
    border: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0) !important;
}
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: First solution.. I think too much spaces. if that classes from one element it shout be without spaces. for example  .ui-checkboxradio-checked.ui-state-active

Second solution should work after hard refresh (ctrl + f5 or ctrl + shit+ r for chrome)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cheked example link. All classes in one element, so it shoud be like that(without spaces):

```
.ui-checkboxradio-label.ui-corner-all.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-checkboxradio-checked.ui-state-active{
     border: 2px solid rgb(255,0,0) !important; 
}
```

and don't forget hard refresh

Comment: Thanks for catching this!  It was indeed the spacing preventing the class to be applied, even the `!important` was redundant after this. I usually disable cache during development in Chrome to avoid related issues.