# Checkbox/Radio how to color buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, background-color, checkboxradio

I have a working Checkboxradio, but I would like to change both the active and inactive color of the buttons. I've gone down several jQuery UI documentation paths that looked like they would work, but I can't seem to get everything in alignment to accomplish this. Below is HTML from my page:

```
<fieldset>
    <label for="checkbox-1">Hot</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
    <label for="checkbox-2">Humid</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
</fieldset>
```

The only javascript that pertains to this is the following script in the  section of my html page (following instructions I saw on the jQuery UI Checkboxradio page:

```
<script>
    $( function() {
    $( "input" ).checkboxradio({
        icon: false,
       });
    });
</script>
```

and these two lines of code in my page body to make sure the checkboxes initially show in the checked state:

```
$('#checkbox-1').prop('checked', true);
$('#checkbox-2').prop('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally came back to this issue, and stumbled on this StackOverflow question: [Customize style for jQuery UI checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46956231/customize-style-for-jquery-ui-checkbox)

The bottom line is that I just needed to add the following CSS, and the button colors for the checkboxradio are now what I wanted:

```
.ui-checkboxradio-label.ui-corner-all.ui-button.ui-widget.ui-checkboxradio-checked.ui-state-active {
    background: #116611; !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This did it - I literally searched everywhere. Also I have to make sure it works on Ipads as well and this did it!

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to look at, is the jQuery UI API docs:

> The checkboxradio widget uses the jQuery UI CSS framework to style its look and feel. If checkboxradio specific styling is needed, the following CSS class names can be used for overrides or as keys for the `classes` option:
>
> - `ui-checkboxradio`: The input of type radio or checkbox. Will be hidden, with its associated label positioned on top.
>
>   - `ui-checkboxradio-label`: The label associated with the input. If the input is checked, this will also get the `ui-checkboxradio-checked` class. If the input is of type radio, this will also get the `ui-checkboxradio-radio-label` class.
>   - `ui-checkboxradio-icon`: If the icon option is enabled, the generated icon has this class.
>   - `ui-checkboxradio-icon-space`: If the icon option is enabled, an extra element with this class as added between the text label and the icon.

In your post, you did not specify what colors you wanted to use; either way, we'd have to assign those via CSS. Looking at your code and the reference above, we can make this example for Green and Red.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#checkbox-1').prop('checked', true);
  $('#checkbox-2').prop('checked', true);
  $("input").checkboxradio({
    icon: false,
  });
});
```

```css
fieldset label.ui-checkboxradio-label {
  border-color: #af0000;
  background: #c80000;
}

fieldset label.ui-checkboxradio-checked {
  border-color: #00af00;
  background: #00c800;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<fieldset>
  <label for="checkbox-1">Hot</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
  <label for="checkbox-2">Humid</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
</fieldset>
```

**Update**

Per your comment, if you wish to use "Checkbox Nested within Label" (E.G.: http://jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/#no-icons ), you must use the Proper HTML markup:

```
<fieldset>
  <label for="checkbox-1">
    Hot
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-1" id="checkbox-1">
  </label>
  <label for="checkbox-2">
    Humid
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-2" id="checkbox-2">
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks, Erik. Putting the two fieldset definitions in makes my site show the red/green colors. So I thought it would be simple then to just change the color codes used, but since there are three colors (hover-over, active, inactive), I'm at a loss as to make them all work. My ideal is actually on the jqueryui dotcom site with this path: /checkboxradio/#no-icons in the "Checkbox nested in label" example. (Blue with white lettering for active button, Black with grey background for inactive, slightly more grey hovering over inactive button, no change when hovering over active button.

Comment: Finally found w3schools css_link page, hopeful that I can now tweak all the color states...

Comment: @JeffRoloff who is Erik? Also, did you look at the Themes for jQuery UI? http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ there are many themes you can use. You can also roll your own.

Comment: Sorry about the wrong name, Twisty. Thanks for the link to the ThemeRoller. Hopefully will have everything looking the way I want by tomorrow.

Comment: I've gone back and forth trying different things today, but not getting anywhere. I did add "border-radius: 4px;" to both styles, which work great. I also added 

    .button {
        -webkit-transition-duration: 0.4s; /* Safari */
        transition-duration: 0.4s;
    }

Comment: My main issue is the same: I can't figure out how to replicate the jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/ Checkbox nested in label example (the bed type). Sorry this has been so hard for me to figure out. Any help is appreciated! Really wish that jQuery examples had full code (including CSS)!

Comment: What I really want is the "Checkbox nested in label" example on the jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/#no-icons page. Seems CSS should be included in their examples. I've tried so many variations of things, but nothing is exactly right. Thanks for any help you have for me!

Comment: @JeffRoloff see my update. You must use the proper HTML for that.

Comment: thanks for laboring on with this. Changing the HTML made no difference in operation - I put one of each, and behavior is identical. It seems that this is all a CSS issue now, and I wish I could somehow get the CSS for "Checkbox nested in label" example on the jqueryui.com/checkboxradio/#no-icons page. Colors, behavior, everything. But I have no idea what CSS is styling that beautiful example! It's exactly the behavior/colors/etc. that I would like on my page.